# Databind chart with members from a field instance

Tags: c#, charts

I would like to put chart series in a List so that I can add new series dynamically. But I have not been able to figure out how to bind the data to the chart when it is structured like this. Maybe its not possible or there are better ways?

```
 public class DataSerie {
        public DataSerie(string _name, double _value) {
            name = _name;
            value = _value;
        }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
    }
    public class ChartData
    {
        public ChartData(double _x)
        {
            x = _x;
            series = new List<DataSerie>();
        }
        public double x { get; set; }
        public List<DataSerie> series { get; set; }
    }
    private List<ChartData> chartDataList = new List<ChartData>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChartData cd;

        cd = new ChartData(1);
        cd.series.Add(new DataSerie("y1", 5));
        cd.series.Add(new DataSerie("y2", 3));
        cd.series.Add(new DataSerie("y3", 3));
        chartDataList.Add(cd);

        cd = new ChartData(2);
        cd.series.Add(new DataSerie("y1", 5));
        cd.series.Add(new DataSerie("y2", 4));
        cd.series.Add(new DataSerie("y3", 2));
        chartDataList.Add(cd);

        chart1.DataSource = chartDataList;
        chart1.Series.Clear();

        ChartData c = chartDataList[0];
        foreach (DataSerie serie in c.series) {
            chart1.Series.Add(serie.name);
            chart1.Series[serie.name].XValueMember = "X";
            chart1.Series[serie.name].YValueMembers = "serie.value"; // This obviously doesnt work. 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by iterating over the data and populate the chart like this: `chart.Series[serie.name].Points.AddXY(data.x,data.y);`

Instead of databinding